# Ember.js routing: how do you set a default route to render immediately?

Tags: routes, ember.js, ember-old-router

I'm sure this will become clear as I dig in deeper, but for now it's not obvious how to make this happen.

I was following the info on [this helpful SO article about routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050956/ember-js-router-action-to-controller) but there is an important piece missing from the example, i.e. how do you get the 'home' view to render right away without having to click the 'home' link?

I've started digging into the docs to try to make sense of this, but meanwhile it seems like a useful question to have answered for posterity.

I've been playing with the working jsfiddle example from the above question [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rzNuZ/15/) and comparing with this other example I found that [seems to have the default routing working](http://jsfiddle.net/zdfs/qsAxZ/5/)

So far it's still a mystery.

**Current code**:

```js
App.Router = Em.Router.extend({
  enableLogging: true,
  location: 'hash',

  root: Em.State.extend({
    // EVENTS
    goHome: Ember.State.transitionTo('home'),
    viewProfile: Ember.State.transitionTo('profile'),

    // STATES
    index: Em.State.extend({
        route: "/",
        redirectsTo: 'home'
    }),

    home: Em.State.extend({
        route: '/home',
        connectOutlets: function(router, context) {
            var appController = router.get('applicationController');
            appController.connectOutlet('home');
        }
    }),

    // STATES
    profile: Em.State.extend({
        route: '/profile',
            connectOutlets: function(router, context) {
              var appController = router.get('applicationController');
              appController.connectOutlet('profile');
            }
        }),
        doOne: function() {
            alert("eins");
        }
  }) 
});
```

---

**UPDATE: Solution**

It turns out that the reason the example I was working with was not working was because it was using `Em.State.extend` rather than `Em.Route.extend`. The interesting part is that as I step through and change them over one by one the example doesn't work until I change all of them over.

Here is the working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/fSgZS/):

```js
App.Router = Em.Router.extend({
  enableLogging: true,
  location: 'hash',

  root: Em.Route.extend({
    // EVENTS
    goHome: Ember.State.transitionTo('home'),
    viewProfile: Ember.State.transitionTo('profile'),

    // STATES
    index: Em.Route.extend({
        route: "/",
        redirectsTo: 'home'
    }),

    home: Em.Route.extend({
        route: '/home',
        connectOutlets: function(router, context) {
            var appController = router.get('applicationController');
            appController.connectOutlet({name: 'home'});
        }
    }),

    // STATES
    profile: Em.Route.extend({
        route: '/profile',
            connectOutlets: function(router, context) {
              var appController = router.get('applicationController');
              appController.connectOutlet('profile');
            }
        }),
        doOne: function() {
            alert("eins");
        }
  }) 
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a redirect from the index to the home route:

```js
// Default route
$(function() {
    App = Em.Application.create();

    // Instantiated and wired up for you in App.initialize()
    App.ApplicationController = Em.Controller.extend();
    App.ApplicationView = Em.View.extend({
        templateName: 'application'
    });
    
    App.NavController = Em.Controller.extend({});
    App.NavView = Em.View.extend({ templateName: 'nav' });
    
    App.HomeController = Em.Controller.extend({});
    App.HomeView = Em.View.extend({ templateName: 'home' });
    
    App.ProfileController = Em.Controller.extend({});
    App.ProfileView = Em.View.extend({ templateName: 'profile' });
    
    App.Router = Em.Router.extend({
        enableLogging: true,
        location: 'hash',

        root: Em.Route.extend({
            goHome: Ember.State.transitionTo('home'),
            goProfile: Ember.State.transitionTo('profile'),
            
            index: Em.Route.extend({
                route: '/',
                redirectsTo: 'home'
            }),

            home: Em.Route.extend({
                route: '/home',

                connectOutlets: function(router, context) {
                    router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet({
                        name: 'home'
                    });
                }
            }),
            
            profile: Em.Route.extend({
                route: '/profile',

                connectOutlets: function(router, context) {
                    console.log("enter");
                    router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet({
                        name: 'profile'
                    });
                }
            })
        })
    });

    App.initialize();
});
```

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    {{view App.NavView controllerBinding="controller.controllers.navController"}}
    <hr />
    <div class="content">
        {{outlet}}
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="nav">
    <h1>navigation:</h1>
    <button {{action goHome}}>home</button>
    <button {{action goProfile}}>profile</buton>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="home">
    <h1>Home...</h1>
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="profile">
    <h1>Profile...</h1>
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the working example. It took me a while to figure out what the difference was from my example above but I finally figured it out. The example I gave didn't work because it was using `Em.State.extend` rather than `Em.Route.extend`

Answer (score 9):

It seems this is done diffently now. I had success with this way of doing it:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  // 'index' route is default
  this.resource('dashboard');
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    redirect: function() {
        // this redirects / to /dashboard
        this.transitionTo('dashboard');
    }
});

App.DashboardRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
});
```

Answer (score 9):

With Ember CLI, you can put the redirect in index.js in your root of routes directory:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend( {
  redirect: function() {
    this.transitionTo('dashboard');
  }
});
```