# Emberjs: Router issues

Tags: ember.js, ember-old-router

I am new to Ember but I like it a lot. Currently, I am experiencing with the `Router`. However, I guess I don't really get it. This is the code I am using (taken from Emberjs's website):

```js
App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
      root: Ember.State.extend({
        index: Ember.State.extend({
          route: '/',
          redirectsTo: 'posts'
        }),
        posts: Ember.State.extend({
          route: '/posts'
        }),
        post: Ember.State.extend({
          route: '/posts/:post_id'
        })
      })
    });
```

However, this code does nothing for me. Isn't it supposed to change the address to `/posts` when I hit the `index`? Am I doing something wrong? Thank you :)

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165315/ember-js-routing-how-do-you-set-a-default-route-to-render-immediately, you can find a working Router redirectsTo example in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use Ember.Route rather than Ember.State, since the routing-specific code was separated from Ember.StateManager / Ember.State.

Comment: ok, I changed State to Route. It does nothing. Shouldn't it change the url to `/posts` when I get onto the index page?

Comment: Do you have ApplicationController/View? Do you call App.initialize()?